# Cassandra sstableloader Failed attempt 2 to connect to non-seed node

Tags: connection, cassandra, cluster-computing, nodes

I am trying to load sstables using cassandra utility sstable-loader with cassandra 0.8.3 on a cluster of two nodes.
It successfully completes the gossip but after that it shows no progress with following error message

progress: [ip_nonseed 0/44 (0)] [ip_seed 0/44 (0)] [total: 0 - 0MB/s (avg: 0MB/s)] WARN 11:10:39,692 **Failed attempt 2 to connect to /ip_nonseed to stream AudienceNetwork/Audience-g-15-Data.db sections=3 progress=0/160960015 - 0%. Retrying in 40000 ms. (java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException)**

Thanks
samarth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the same hostname problem as your other question.  Issue [CASSANDRA-3044](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3044) is fixed in 0.8.5; you can test that by following the link on the release thread [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-dev/201109.mbox/%3CCAKkz8Q12k2o7ZM5Uy9hxNk7kYEsQidwcyXbq_uZFnA+YaTYXLA@mail.gmail.com%3E).